# Haskell error: "First argument in (n+k) pattern must be a variable" - but how?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create an infinite list of pythagorean values, but I've run into a problem.

```
pytrips = [(x, y, z) | z <- [1..], y <- [1..z], x <- [1..y],
           (x^2 + y^2) <- z^2, gcd x y == 1]
```

My error reads thusly:

`"First argument in (n+k) pattern must be a variable"`

I don't quite understand what syntax issue I'm making for this to be so, since the method shouldn't need any arguments passed into it. Could anyone help me clear this up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably meant to write `==` instead of `<-`:

```
pytrips = [(x, y, z) | z <- [1..], y <- [1..z], x <- [1..y],
           x^2 + y^2 == z^2, gcd x y == 1]
```

Comment: Yes, yes I did, thank you!
...The moment I can get a break from work, the better.